# How to completely revert gem version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to revert the 'bootstrap' gem from 'alpha6' to 'alpha3'.

I've run:

```
 $ gem uninstall bootstrap

        Select gem to uninstall:
         1. bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha3
         2. bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6
         3. All versions
        > 2

Successfully uninstalled bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6`
```

but when I try to start the server I get:

```
$ rails server
  Could not find bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6 in any of the sources
  Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

here's what's in my gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha3'
```

rails is still looking for alpha6. how do I tell rails to forget about alpha 6 and move on with it's life?

Comment: What's in your gemfile?

Comment: Make sure that the gemfile has the bootstrap gem listed with the desired version (Should be something like:   gem 'Gem Name Here', 'Version Here'  and then run: "bundle install" to add the desired gem back into the package now that you've uninstalled it.

Comment: @bkunzi01 here's what I have in my gemfile: `gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha3'`. Why isn't it respecting what's in my gemfile? I don't have alpha6 anywhere. I've run bundle install and it always pulls alpha6

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it:

run:

```
$ gem uninstall bootstrap
Successfully uninstalled bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha6
```

add the gem like this in your Gemfile, getting rid of the **~>**

```
gem 'bootstrap', '4.0.0.alpha3'
```

run

```
$ bundle install
```

hopefully you see the nice message:

```
Installing bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha3 (was 4.0.0.alpha6)
```